# Showing notification in broadcast receiver

Tags: android

HI,
I am in a situation that I need to display notification when call arrives. For this I am using broadcast receiver. Code is below

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //Get the icon for the notification
            int icon = R.drawable.icon;
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon,"Simple Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());

            //Setup the Intent to open this Activity when clicked
            Intent toLaunch = new Intent(context, main.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, toLaunch, 0);

            //Set the Notification Info
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Hi!!", "This is a simple notification", contentIntent);

            //Setting Notification Flags
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
          //  notification.sound = Uri.withAppendedPath(Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "6");
            //Send the notification
            notifier.notify(0x007, notification);
            Log.d("CALL", "IDLE");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
          Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

          Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
        break;
        }
    }

}
```

Now problem is that sound for the notification is not playing but notification is being displayed correctly. Can anyone shed light on it please why notification sound is not being played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up playing sound manually via media player. Code Now Looks like

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public Context context;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ealertprefs";
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                     
            Log.v("CALL", "IDLE");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
          Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          if(call_from_elist(incomingNumber)) {
              wake_up_phone();
              send_notification();
              create_sound();
          }
          Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
        break;
        }
    }
    private boolean call_from_elist(String number) {
        return true;
    }
    private void wake_up_phone() {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    }
    private void send_notification(){
        NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);                
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon,"Simple Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());        
        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(context, main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, toLaunch, 0);        
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Hi!!", "This is a simple notification", contentIntent);        
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;                              
        notifier.notify(0x007, notification);
    }
    private void create_sound() {
        Uri alert;
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String ringtone = settings.getString("ringtone_uri", "");
        if(ringtone.equals("")) {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        else {
            alert = Uri.parse(ringtone);
        }

        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
            //final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            //if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION) != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
                //mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            //}
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v("CALL", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

to

```
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Comment: not working... I think this is a bug in android..Should I report it there?